# How can I cache custom views in my ListView Adapter?

Tags: java, android, android-listview

In my `ImageAdapter` (extends `BaseAdapter`), each `View` is a custom view I called `ImageTapView`. It's a separate class that extends `RelativeLayout` with its own layout file that starts with a `<merge>`. This class contains all the click listeners, loaders for the images that each `ImageTapView` downloads and displays from the internet, as well as animations that happen on click.

Here's my `ImageAdapter` constructor:

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context context;
    private JSONArray posts;
    private String baseUrl;
    private HashMap views = new HashMap();

    public ImageAdapter(Context _context, JSONArray _posts, String _baseUrl){
        context = _context;
        posts = _posts;
        baseUrl = _baseUrl;            
    }

    ...etc
}
```

In my `ImageAdapter.getView` everything works fine if I do something like:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
    // create new imageTapView
    JSONObject thisPost = posts.getJSONObject(position);
    convertView = new ImageTapView(context, thisPost);
    return convertView;
}
```

But this means Android is creating a new `ImageTapView` every time it calls `getView` instead of just replacing the data in the already inflated view. I think it'd be way harder to go in and replace each field and reset the animations on `getView`, not to mention, I'd like the user to see where in their interaction with `ImageTapView` they left off (e.g. zoomed in on an image or in the middle of an animation).

I tried saving each view to a `HashMap` called `views`:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
    if(views.containsKey(position)) return (ImageTapView) views.get(position);
    // create new imageTapView
    JSONObject thisPost = posts.getJSONObject(position);
    convertView = new ImageTapView(context, thisPost);
    views.put(position, convertView);
    return convertView;
}
```

But I get some very strange behavior. `ImageTapViews` that are on, say, step 2 of 3 steps of interaction (start state, zoomed state, information overlay shown state), things get really strange. They don't seem to pick up where they left off and they don't respond to clicks the proper way a fresh `ImageTapView` would.

So is there a standard way of caching objects or custom objects in a `ListView`? Should I be extending `ArrayAdapter` instead, or would my problem be the same in the `getView` function?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this ,you need create extra method setPost() to set post

```
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
      // create new imageTapView
      JSONObject thisPost = posts.getJSONObject(position);
      if(convertView==null)
            convertView = new ImageTapView(context, thisPost);
      else{
      ((ImageTapView)convertView).setPost(thisPost); 
      }
     return convertView;
 }
```

Comment: I guess this is the only / best way to do this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

1. Custom item layout for your adapter.

**row.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <packageName.ImageTapView>
        android:id="@+id/imageTapView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    </packageName.ImageTapView>
</LinearLayout>
```

2. inflate custom row layout in adapter.

   public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

   ```
   private Context context;
   private JSONArray posts;
   private String baseUrl;
   private HashMap views = new HashMap();

   public ImageAdapter(Context _context, JSONArray _posts, String _baseUrl){
       context = _context;
       posts = _posts;
       baseUrl = _baseUrl;
   }

   static class ViewHolder
   {
       ImageTapView imageTapView;
   }

   @Override
   public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
       ViewHolder viewHolder;
       if (convertView == null) {
           viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
           convertView = LayoutInflater.from(_context).inflate(R.layout.row, null);
           viewHolder.imageTapView = (ImageTapView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageTapView);
           convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
       } else {
           viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
       }
       viewHolder.imageTapView.setPost(posts.getJSONObject(position));
       return convertView;
   }

   ...etc
   ```

   }